# Correct way to avoid similar duplicate catch block used by two different methods?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, instanceof

I am having two different methods, that does different work, but there catch block is same.

```
Method A :
    try{
    doAstuff();
    }
    catch(ExceptionA){
    }
    catch(ExceptionB){
    }
    ..........
    catch(Exception)
    {
    }

Method B:
   try{
    doBstuff();
    }
    catch(ExceptionA){
    }
    catch(ExceptionB){
    }
    ..........
    catch(Exception)
    {
    }
```

I want to have one common catch block to avoid duplicate code.So I am thinking of

```
Method A:
 

    try{
     doAstuff();
     }
     catch(Exception e){
     handlexception(e);
        }

Method B:
      try{
     doBstuff();
     }
     catch(Exception e){
     handlexception(e);
        }

handlexception(Exception e){
if( e instaceOf Exception_A)

handle(A)

else If   ( e instaceOf Exception_B)
handle(B)
....
....

}
```

IS there a better way where I can avoid instanceOf or use something better?May be switch case ladder or something?

Comment: Very hard to give general advice here, and there is little specific context, but to me this pattern indicates that you might need to introduce another level of abstraction somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ExceptionA extends Exception {}
class ExceptionB extends Exception {}
// ...
class ExceptionN extends Exception {}

interface CatchedMethod {
    void run() throws ExceptionA, ExceptionB, ..., ExceptionN;
}

void catchMethod(CatchedMethod k) {
    try {
        k.run();
    } catch (ExceptionA ea) {
        ...
    } catch (ExceptionB exceptionB) {
        ...
    ...
    } catch (ExceptionN exceptionN) {
        ...
    }
}

void method1() {
    catchMethod(() -> {
        ... code 1 ...
    });
}

void method2() {
    catchMethod(() -> {
        ... code 2 ...
    });
}
```